# Is it possible to make an opam "sandbox"?

Tags: ocaml, opam

I have two ocaml projects being compiled with ocaml 4.02.1. Is there a way to create separate opam installations for each project instead of having both projects install their dependencies in the global 4.02.1 opam switch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `opam` you can have several installations of the same compiler:

```
opam switch -A 4.02.1 proj1
opam switch -A 4.02.1 proj2
```

will create two separate independent stacks for each project. You may also find these commands useful:

```
opam switch export
opam switch import
```

Comment: If you alias the `system` compiler, OPAM also does a "fast switch" that doesn't require reinstalling everything.  So you could do `opam switch -A system proj1`, assuming that your system compiler is 4.01.0

Comment: The `-A` option was removed in `opam` 2.1 . For now, we should use the following command to create a switch: `opam switch create <name> <compiler version>`.