# Running `eval $(something)` commands using Python sub-process

Tags: python, linux, eval

I have the following subprocess/command I run inside terminal:

`$ eval $(docker-machine env machine-name)`

I assumed the python equivalent would be:

`sp = subprocess.run(["eval", "$(docker-machine env {})".format(self.project_machine_name)])`

or perhaps:

`sp = subprocess.run(["eval", "$(docker-machine", "env", "{})".format(self.project_machine_name)])`

However, neither of the above seem to work.

I was wondering, how would I run the above `eval` within a python script...

**N.B**. *For brevity, assume self.project_machine_name = 'machine-name'*

This is not the same as calling a sub-process as it needs to be `eval()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: @buran This is not a duplicate - this is using eval() by fetching the output from a command.

Comment: if you want the output of external command instead of subprocess.run() use `subporcess.check_output()`. still it's a duplicate , e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output

Comment: how do I run `    command: str = f"eval $(opam env --switch={switch} --set-switch)"
    res = subprocess.run(command.split(), check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` **inside of python**?

Comment: related: https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/is-eval-opam-env-switch-switch-set-switch-equivalent-to-opam-switch-set-switch/10957

Comment: aren't answers missing `.decode()` for the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
sp = subprocess.run(['docker-machine', 'env', self.project_machine_name])
```

More info and additional arguments - [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

EDIT: if you want the output, use `subprocess.check_output()` instead.

Comment: I originally tried this, and assumed at that point that it didn't work...my thought is why is this equivalent to `eval($ something)`...?

Comment: Nope - sorry this hasn't worked actaully. I need to evaluate the above sub-process.

Comment: well, `$ eval $(docker-machine env machine-name)` will construct command `docker-machine env machine-name` and execute it. that is exactly what my suggestion would do. It doesn't make sense to construct a command that will construct another command and execute the later... As described in the [man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/eval/): "The eval utility shall construct a command by concatenating arguments together, separating each with a <space> character.  The constructed command shall be read and executed by the shell."

Comment: All I can say is if I run the sub-processes manually - it works. And your method doesn't. That is all I can say I'm afraid.

Comment: "if I run the sub-processes manually - it works." - I don't get why do you ask if you know the correct syntax to invoke `subprocess.run()` - just use it.  And note that "your method doesn't [work]" is extremely uninformative...

Comment: And I am not running `docker-machine env machine-name`, I am running `eval($ docker-machine env machine-name)`.

Comment: Manually from the terminal.

Comment: It's not uninformative - you've jumped in saying to try something, and when I have tried it - it doesn't work. Please delete answer. The `eval($)` command configures my shell.

Comment: how do I run `    command: str = f"eval $(opam env --switch={switch} --set-switch)"
    res = subprocess.run(command.split(), check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` **inside of python**?

Comment: aren't you missing `.decode()` for the output?

Answer (score -1):

It depends what you're trying to do but I may be doing something similar. I'm building my dockers in minikube and have a python script that I use to build those dockers.

Before I run the docker build I need to make sure the right environment variables are set, meaning I need to run

```
eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)
```

Which generates a bunch of statements that you're meant to run in the shell (typically with an eval)

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.49.2:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/home/aluchko/.minikube/certs"
export MINIKUBE_ACTIVE_DOCKERD="minikube"

# To point your shell to minikube's docker-daemon, run:
# eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)
```

To be able to trigger my builds in python I need these environment variables set when I my docker build commands.

Now there's basically two ways to do this (aside from doing the eval in a wrapper around your script). Both ways involve getting the that string with the export commands.

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['minikube', '-p', 'minikube', 'docker-env'])
```

1. Parse the results of the minikube (or docker-machine command) and set those variables in the shell for future subprocesses. You can be a bit sloppy with the RE since you know the output of the docker-machine command. The shell=True is just for the echo.

   ```
   output = subprocess.check_output(['minikube', '-p', 'minikube', 'docker-env'])

   import re
   export_re = re.compile('export ([A-Z\_]+)="(.*)"\\n')
   export_pairs = export_re.findall(output.decode("UTF-8"))

   build_env = os.environ.copy()

   for k,v in export_pairs:
       build_env[k] = v

   subprocess.run('echo $DOCKER_HOST', shell=True, env=build_env)
   ```
2. A bit sloppier, and more prone to injection attacks, just sandwich the strings together so all your commands are basically a script that starts with a bunch of exports, this isn't nearly as clean and locks you into using the shell=True subprocess functionality, but it does work.

   ```
   output = subprocess.check_output(['minikube', '-p', 'minikube', 'docker-env'])
   extended_output = output + b"\necho $DOCKER_HOST"
   print(extended_output)

   subprocess.run(extended_output, shell=True)
   ```

Comment: how do I run `    command: str = f"eval $(opam env --switch={switch} --set-switch)"
    res = subprocess.run(command.split(), check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` **inside of python**?

Comment: aren't you missing `.decode()` for the output?